# AspNetBoilerplate REACT template - error after npm start

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Today I downloaded the ABP Asp.Net Core REACT SPA template. After downloading, I ran npm install and then npm start. These two steps worked, no issues.
Once the REACT app has started, the browser opens up and all I get is a blank page. Then after a few seconds the below error dialog box comes up. 
[image]
When I look at the chrome console, I find the errors shown below.
[image]
I'm new to REACT and very much still learning it. So I could use some help in tracking this error down. 
Please note I did run the migrator project and got the DB setup on my PC and updated the connection strings to ensure connectivity for the .NET code.

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps below to check whether you miss any step:

1. VS 2019 Open abp project
2. Change `YourProjectName.Web.Host` -> `appsettings.json` -> `ConnectionStrings.Default`
3. From VS 2019 PMC, set `YourProjectName.EntityFrameworkCore` as Default Project
4. Run `update-database` which will create the database
5. Set `YourProjectName.Web.Host` as Start Project, and run `YourProjectName.Web.Host`
6. For expected result, you will get `http://localhost:21021/swagger/index.html`
7. CD `reactjs` folder and run `npm install` and `npm start`
8. `http://localhost:3000/user/login` will show up.

Comment: then what's next? How can I log in?